# Can I put a UIScrollView inside another UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIScrollView` which scrolls only in vertical direction, I need to place `UIScrollView` which can move horizontally, like the AppStore application in apple devices. I don't want to us `UICollectionView` since I have static data and I have to only 3 horizontal `UIScrollView`

Comment: you can subclass uiscrollview to give it properties like parent child or simply give tags to identify which scrollview is which.

Comment: Yes, It is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. As `UIScrollView` subclasses `UIView` it will behave as expected when adding subviews. Each scroll view will enable scrolling based on its `contentSize` property.

**Objective-C:**

```
UIScrollView *horizontalScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
horizontalScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
horizontalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0, 300.0);
[self.view addSubview:horizontalScrollView];

UIScrollView *verticalScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 220.0, 220.0)];
verticalScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
verticalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(220.0, 2000.0);
[horizontalScrollView addSubview:verticalScrollView];
```

**Swift:**

```
let horizontalScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 300.0, 300.0))
horizontalScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
horizontalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0, 300.0)
self.view.addSubview(horizontalScrollView)

let verticalScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 220.0, 220.0))
verticalScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
verticalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(220.0, 2000.0)
horizontalScrollView.addSubview(verticalScrollView)
```

[image: Nested scroll views in action]

Comment: What do I do if I have two scrollviews in the same direction？

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. But you need to differentiate the scroll views in scroll view delegate methods. Either you can use tags or if you are declaring them as global variables in the entire class,you can directly access them with their names.Eg:

```
UIScrollView *parentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
parentScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:parentScrollView];

UIScrollView *childScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
childScrollView.delegate = self;
[parentScrollView addSubview:childScrollView];
```

Now inside delegate method you can check for the scroll view like

```
if(scrollview == parentScrollview)
{
// do your actions
}
```

This is possible only if your scroll view objects are global to the class. You can also give a tag and check for the tag in scroll view delegate method like

```
parentScrollView. tag = 101;
```

And in scroll view delegate method

```
if(scrollview.tag = 101)
    {
    // do your actions
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible but you have to maintain tag of scrollview for handling delegate methods of scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollView has a property called `scrollEnabled`, which you can set to NO to disable scrolling in your parent scroll view.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == innerView)
        outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    else
        outerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == innerView)
    {
         if(innerView.contentOffset.x + innerView.frame.size.width == innerView.contentSize.width)
         {
              outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;
         }
         else
         {
              outerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
         }
    }
}
```

Or else you can go through the below [link](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/).