# Multiple scrollviews inside each other

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have a vertical paged scrollview inside a horizontal scrollview.
The horizontal scrollview works but the vertical one does not.

I used `scrollView.contentSize=CGSize(500,2000)` on vertical scrollview but it is still not working.

Now what is the problem?

I should say, the vertical one added to view, programmatically using xib.

this is my **Main.swift** (i have no storyboard):

```
class test: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let myView3:TourDetailsDescription = TourDetailsDescription(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scroll.frame.width, height: scroll.frame.height))
    myView3.getView().frame.origin.x = CGFloat(2*scroll.frame.width)
    scroll.addSubview(myView3)

    let img1:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "kavir"))
    img1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 600)
    myView3.mainScroll.addSubview(img1)
    myView3.mainScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 600)


    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(2), height:self.scroll.frame.height)
}
}
```

and my **TourDetailsDescription.swift** :

class TourDetailsDescription: UIView {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainScroll: UIScrollView!
var parent:UIView!
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commitInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commitInit()
}
private func commitInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TourDetailsDescription", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}

func getView()->UIView{
    return contentView
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I put a UIScrollView inside another UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408306/can-i-put-a-uiscrollview-inside-another-uiscrollview)

Comment: @pascal_AC tnx, but not at all.

Comment: Does it work if you load the vertical scroll outside of the horizontal scroll view?

Comment: @MXV yes of course. even if its inside without adding from xib, its loading. the problem is from adding scroll view from xib. can u help pls ?

Comment: Need a bit more information about your structure. Is *everything* in one .xib? Or you have a "vertical scroll view" in a .xib, and you're loading that into a horizontal scroll view that already exists?

Comment: @DonMag the second one is right my friend. vertical second view is in xib, and horizontal is in another xib.i load the horizontal one in vertical one's xib

Comment: OK - you need to show a little more of the code you are using. It's easy to load scroll views from xibs, so without seeing your code there is no way to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: @DonMag i added my codes my friend

Comment: @FaridFaa - couple notes... First, don't create and/or add Subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` - that will be called multiple times, and you end up with multiple copies of views. Next, you say you have no Storyboard, but I don't see how / where you are instantiating `class test: UIViewController`? So it appears `test` is associated with a XIB that contains only a ScrollView, which you size to "full screen"... and you want to add a ContentView that contains a ScrollView? Or you want to add a ScrollView that contains a ContentView? And no auto-layout / constraints?

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you :), this is working on playground

```
class ScrollingViewController : UIViewController {

override func loadView() {

    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 2000, height: 200))
    contentView.backgroundColor = .green

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white

    let verticalContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    verticalContainerView.backgroundColor = .blue

    let verticalContentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 2000))
    verticalContentView.backgroundColor = .red

    let verticalScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: verticalContainerView.frame)
    verticalScrollView.contentSize = verticalContentView.frame.size
    verticalScrollView.addSubview(verticalContentView)
    scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
    verticalScrollView.backgroundColor = .white

    verticalContainerView.addSubview(verticalScrollView)

    contentView.addSubview(verticalContainerView)

    self.view = scrollView
}

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ScrollingViewController()
```

Comment: I want to add it from xib. I think the problem is from constraints and autoresizes

Comment: Take a look to the setup, and with the content views inside the scroll views, which are the views that set the size inside the scrollableView